# Слияние двух разных массивов, разной длины.

Tags: массивы, php

```
    $n_a_author = array();
    foreach($_POST['name'] as $key=>$value){
    $n = array('',$value,$_POST['alias'][$key]);
    $n_a_author[] = $n;
    }
    echo wtf($n_a_author); // Решение и результат.
           Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => Roza
            [2] => Ro
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => Sara
            [2] => Sa
        )
)
```

P.s. Решение найдено, но появилась новая проблема. Как ассоциативный массив теперь преобразовать в строку?Чтоб можно было добавить в БД. Пробовал *implode(',',$n_a_author)*,но выскакивает ошибка **Notice: Array to string conversion in**

Comment: приведите пожалуйста пару примеров входных данных и ожидаемых выходных. Очень сложно угадать, как именно Вы хотите сделать слияние.

Comment: А сразу на стороне клиента массив формировать как `name="INPUT[i][name]" name="INPUT[i][alias]"` никак? Ну а что касается кода - почему циклы вложены? Какой в это смысл вкладывается?

Comment: > Чтоб можно было добавить в БД.

json_encode?

Comment: http://www.php.su/serialize

Answer (score 1):

Для этого есть php функция: [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

Comment: Jeix, используя array_merge, я получаю лишь один элемент из массива,последний - 1,22,222. А хотелось бы,чтоб было (1,11,111),(2,22,222).